# Project Reactor: doOnNext (or the others doOnXXX) async

Tags: java, asynchronous, project-reactor, reactive-streams

Is there any method like doOnNext, but async?
For example, I need to do some long logging (sent notification by email) for determined element.

```
Scheduler myParallel = Schedulers.newParallel("my-parallel", 4);

Flux<Integer> ints = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        .publishOn(myParallel)
        .doOnNext(v -> {
            // For example, we need to do something time-consuming only for 3

            if (v.equals(3)) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("LOG FOR " + v);
        });

ints.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

But why should I wait for logging of 3? I want to do this logic asynchronously.

Now I have only this solution

```
Thread.sleep(10000);

Scheduler myParallel = Schedulers.newParallel("my-parallel", 4);
Scheduler myParallel2 = Schedulers.newParallel("my-parallel2", 4);

Flux<Integer> ints = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        .publishOn(myParallel)
        .doOnNext(v -> {
            Mono.just(v).publishOn(myParallel2).subscribe(value -> {
                if (value.equals(3)) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("LOG FOR " + value);
            });
        });

ints.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Is there any "nice" solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure you don't care wether or not the email sending succeeds, then you *could* use "subscribe-inside-doOnNext" but I'm pretty confident that would be a mistake.

In order to have your `Flux` propagate an `onError` signal if the "logging" fails, the recommended approach is to use `flatMap`.

The good news is that since `flatMap` merges results from the inner publishers immediately into the main sequence, you can get still emit each element immediately AND trigger the email. The only caveat is that the whole thing will only **complete** once the email-sending `Mono` has also completed. You can also check within the `flatMap` lambda if the logging needs to happen at all (rather than inside the inner `Mono`):

```
//assuming sendEmail returns a Mono<Void>, takes care of offsetting any blocking send onto another Scheduler

source //we assume elements are also publishOn as relevant in `source`
   .flatMap(v -> {
       //if we can decide right away wether or not to send email, better do it here
       if (shouldSendEmailFor(v)) {
           //we want to immediately re-emit the value, then trigger email and wait for it to complete
           return Mono.just(v)
               .concatWith(
                   //since Mono<Void> never emits onNext, it is ok to cast it to V
                   //which makes it compatible with concat, keeping the whole thing a Flux<V>
                   sendEmail(v).cast(V.class)
               );
       } else {
           return Mono.just(v);
       }
    });
```

Comment: "If you're absolutely sure you don't care wether or not the email sending succeeds, then you could use "subscribe-inside-doOnNext" but I'm pretty confident that would be a mistake" -- that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

```
    Flux<Integer> ints = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            .flatMap(integer -> {
                        if (integer != 3) {
                            return Mono.just(integer)
                                    .map(integer1 -> {
                                        System.out.println(integer1);
                                        return integer;
                                    })
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
                        } else {
                            return Mono.just(integer)
                                    .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
                                    .map(integer1 -> {
                                        System.out.println(integer1);
                                        return integer;
                                    })
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
                        }
                    }

            );

    ints.subscribe();
```